# Sorting a dataframe by another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have an initial dataframe X:

```
   x  y  z  w
0  1  a  b  c
1  1  d  e  f
2  0  g  h  i
3  0  k  l  m
4 -1  n  o  p
5 -1  q  r  s
6 -1  t  v  à
```

with many columns and rows (this is a toy example). After applying some Machine Learning procedures, I get back a similar dataframe, but with the -1s changed to 0s or 1s and the rows sorted in a different way; for example:

```
   x  y  z  w
4  1  n  o  p
0  1  a  b  c
6  0  t  v  à
1  1  d  e  f
2  0  g  h  i
5  0  q  r  s
3  0  k  l  m
```

How could I do in order to sort the second dataframe as the first one? For example, like

```
   x  y  z  w
0  1  a  b  c
1  1  d  e  f
2  0  g  h  i
3  0  k  l  m
4  1  n  o  p
5  0  q  r  s
6  0  t  v  à
```

Comment: if you still have the index like in your example, then `sort_index` might be enough?

Comment: Or another way : `df2.reindex_like(df1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't trust just sorting the indexes (e.g. if the first `df`'s indexes are not sorted, or if you have something other than `RangeIndex`), just use `loc`

```
df2.loc[df.index]
```

---

```
   x  y  z  w
0  1  a  b  c
1  1  d  e  f
2  0  g  h  i
3  0  k  l  m
4  1  n  o  p
5  0  q  r  s
6  0  t  v  à
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

It restores the order, just by index